# Make a connection Entity Framework dynamic

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a connection string and I can do it without a problem

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DbName" 
         connectionString="server=serverName;database=DbTest;user=x;pwd=xxx;"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"  />
</connectionStrings>
```

and I have the connection of Entity Framework:

```
public DbContext1() : base("DbName")
{
}
```

But I need to make a query to `DbContext1` to get a new string connection from a table to connect to an other database, but I do not know how use the string connection that I receive from the query.

How can I use the string connection from the table to make a new `DbContext`?

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
public DbContext1(string connString) : base(connString)
{
}
```

The constructor your derived class needs call is [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbcontext.-ctor?view=entity-framework-6.2.0#System_Data_Entity_DbContext__ctor_System_String_). The string argument is treated as either a valid connection string itself, or name of a connection string.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a multi-tenant scenario where users authenticate against a central database then get directed to a specific database instance containing their own data. As a simple example during authentication:

```
using (var context = new AuthDbContext())
{ // Where AuthDbContext is the central DB containing authentication and the connection string to that user's home database..
     // ... On successful authentication...
     var connectionString = context.Tenants
         .Where(x => x.TenantId == authenticatedUser.TenantId)
         .Select(x => x.ConnectionString)
         .Single();
}
```

Ideally if you are persisting user details (User ID, name, etc.) to session state then you could load the associated connection string and persist it as part of that data structure as well.

Then create a AppDbContextFactory class or UnitOfWork pattern class to inject into your services/controllers to provide a DbContext based on the current user's connection string.

As a very basic example:

```
public interface IUserStateFacade
{
    string CurrentUserConnectionString { get; }
}

public class UserSessionState : IUserStateFacade
{
   public const string UserStateSessionName = "UserState";
   public string CurrentUserConnectionString
   {
       get 
       {
           var userState = (UserSessionState)Session[UserStateSessionName] ?? throw new ApplicationException("Session state missing/expired.");
           return userState.ConnectionString;
       }
   }
}

public interface IAppContextFactory
{
    AppContext Create();
}

public class AppContextFactory
{
    private readonly IUserStateFacade _userState = null;
   
    public AppContextFactory(IUserStateFacade userState)
    {
        _userState = userState ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("userState");
    }
    
    /// <summary>
    /// Create a DbContext. Calling code is responsible for disposing.
    /// </summary>
    public AppContext Create()
    {
        return new AppContext(_userState.ConnectionString);
    }
}
```

Then in your controllers etc. that would normally want to create or inject a DbContext with a default constructor would instead use something like:

```
using (var context = AppContextFactory.Create())
{ }
```

or inject a value initialized via the AppContextFactory.

For ASP.Net apps using Session, you may need to wrap `Session` so that an dependency injection library can resolve the connection string/user structure out of the current session state.

Again, this is only a very rudimentary example to outline an option to facilitate dynamic connection strings assuming something like an ASP.Net web application. Additional security measures should be considered but it should hopefully provide some ideas on how it can be structured.